# LuaSocket : What does unconnected:sendto function return?

Tags: lua, udp, udpclient, luasocket

The docs say

> If successful, the method returns 1. In case of error, the method
>   returns nil followed by an error message.

I get a return value of 5.
Even when nil is returned, no error message is returned...

What does "5" return value mean? No. of packets sent or something?

**EDIT**

Here's a gist of the code.

```
local UDPClient = socket.udp()
UDPClient:setsockname("*", 0) --bind on any availible port and localserver ip address.
UDPClient:settimeout(0)
UDPClient:sendto(json.encode{"a"},someIP,somePort)
```

Comment: I guess you're using the library incorrectly. Please post some more code.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz    Thanks for the answer! I have updated the question with the code!

Comment: can you wrap `socket.udp()` into `assert(socket.udp())`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz   Yeah! That makes no difference though!

Comment: I posted it as an answer, though i really have no idea why it works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my computer it returns number of bytes sent in the call. It is weird, indeed, as specification says something completely different.

Comment: Ah Well!  Glad to know that I'm not the only one! 
Thanks a lot anyway! :)

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but it is returning 2 for me as well (which is how many bytes I am trying to send.) Pretty odd the docs haven't been corrected by now..